# How to resolve the real broadcast address for a IPv4 address with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, broadcast, ipv4

Is there any possibility to obtain the "real local" broadcast address for a given IPv4 address with Boost.Asio?

[ip::address_v4::netmask](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/netmask.html) only returns the netmask based on the IPv4 address class, so it cannot be used reliably with the overload of [ip::address_v4::broadcast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/broadcast/overload2.html).

I need to resolve a specific broadcast address for a given (existing) host IPv4 address on the local machine, since I have trouble using an UDP endpoint with a broadcast address of 255.255.255.255.

**Edit:** For clarification, I do not want to resolve a hostname to an IP address or vice versa.

**Edit:** Here is an example:

```
eth0:

host address: 192.168.0.1
net mask...: 255.255.0.0 (**not** class C)
```

So I want to retrieve the broadcast address `192.168.255.255`, but the only input I want to specify is the local net address. Therefore "resolving" or "querying" is the correct term, since I do not want to calculate it.

I have a UDPv4 server, which I bind to a specific local endpoint (by specifying the local IPv4 host address). I want to use this server in both unicast mode and broadcast mode, so I need to specify the remote endpoint as well. I am unable to do this with the "global broadcast" address returned by [ip::address_v4::broadcast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/broadcast/overload1.html), because that always returns `255.255.255.255` which leads to undesired behaviour. In addition to the host address I specify a flag to correctly set the socket option to enable broadcasting via [basic_datagram_socket::broadcast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/broadcast.html).

If you have an example how-to achieve this, I would be grateful. Maybe I am thinking too complicated...

Comment: Did you try to set you broadcast address as the address itself? Another question: did you try broadcast? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/broadcast.html

Comment: @Barry that link is completely unrelated. You're just knee-jerk responding to the word "resolve" (which, I feel, is misused here)

Comment: @Florian With all due respect, I'm baffled why you downvoted my answer, where I show **exactly** how to use `address_v4::broadcast` with a netmask. Your claim that `broadcast()` always returns 255.255.255.255 was just invalid, and had you actually _read_ the answer, complete with the output shown, you'd have seen that. Also, no this is **not** called resolution. You may want to call it derivation or calculation. To resolve, in the context of IP, specifically means using a naming service to resolve host or service addresses.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'real broadcast address for an IPv4 address'. The concept doesn't make sense without the netmask. There is such a thing as a real broadcast address for an IPv4 *address/netmask pair*, as the API indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think indeed the `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast` overloads are what you are after:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    typedef boost::asio::ip::address_v4 A;

    A address = A::from_string("192.168.0.1");

    std::cout << "Address " << address << " has broadcast address " << A::broadcast(address, A::from_string("255.255.0.0")) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Address 192.168.0.1 has broadcast address 192.168.255.255
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/709bcb40884f59f4)**

**Note** Note: if the confusion is from `192.168.0.1` being classified as `Class C`, this is by design.

IANA defines the 16-bit block 192.168.0.0/16 as *"256 contiguous class C networks"* (look at the **[Classful description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#cite_note-3)** The footnote is enlightening, and the Asio implementation matches it).

Comment: No, your answer is exactly what I described in the second paragraph of my question. `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast` does calculate the broadcast address based on the IPv4 address class. I want to get the real broadcast address for a **local** IPv4 address (e. g. `eth0`). I will add an example to my question.

Comment: @FlorianWolters I've simplified my answer after you've clarified your question quite a bit. Hope this helps. (Note: this answer _was already there_, I just removed the DNS lookup that appeared to confuse you)

Comment: Also, added a note about Class C networks at the end of my answer, in case it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. But... How do I automatically get the net mask `255.255.0.0` in your example? I only want to specify the local net address (not the net mask) and retrieve the net mask (in step 1) and afterwards the broadcast address (in step 2) automatically. Therefore I want a mechanism which allows me to resolve a local IPv4 address by its host address **only**. If that is not possible I also have to specify the broadcast address in my application.

Comment: You cannot get a non-standard netmask from _an address_. Maybe you can use platform specific APIs to get it from the NIC configuration, assuming that _it_ is correct. (You don't have to /also/ specify th ebc address. You could use a netmask input or, say e.g. `192.168.0.1/16`)

Comment: OK, thank you very much for explaination. I was afraid that there is no standard way, but hoped that Boost.Asio may use some "magic" to retrieve it with difference OSs. I may use CIDR notation then...